# Can someone explain why I get "Object Required" error

Tags: javascript, html

"I posted a similar question the other day and Thanks to @Alnitak for helping! However, I'm trying to enable/disable/enable 2 links (a href) between 2 given times and receive the "Object required" error.  It's like the id's used lose focus.  page_load function is called via onload.  nStart & nExpired equal Start and End times and I'm using SetInterval instead of setTimeout (I modified Alnitak's code).

I wouldn't have a problem if these were buttons or if I could use PHP, but 'powers that be' would like it via hyperlink.  Please tell me it's possible.. LOL

The error occurs the first line of the second IF condition i.e. making link visible.

```
var myInterval;

function page_load() {
    myInterval = setInterval(function(){ShowLink()},60000);
}

function ShowLink() {
    var now = new Date();
    var clock = now.toTimeString();
    var nStart = 1310;
    var nExpired = 1312;
    var MigTime = 60 * now.getHours() + now.getMinutes();

    var disable = (day === 0 && (MigTime >= nStart && MigTime < nExpired));
    if (disable == true) {
        //hide links
        document.getElementById("prdlnk").style.visibility = "hidden";
        document.getElementById("viewlnk").style.visibility = "hidden";
        document.getElementById("MigMsg").innerHTML= "Scheduled Migration in Progress. Please try later.";

    }

    if (MigTime > nExpired) {
        //visible
        document.getElementById("prdlnk").style.visibility = "visible";
        document.getElementById("viewlnk").style.visibility = "visible";
        document.getElementById("MigMsg").innerHTML= "";
        //     clearInterval(myInterval);
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance,
Vernon

Comment: Your line `document.getElementById(prdlnk').style.visibility = "visible";` is improperly quoted.

Comment: improperly quoted has been corrected.  Still doesn't work. Point of failure occurs in the second IF condition...the first attempt to make it visible

Answer (score 1):

Could be a bad copy paste, but this line is missing a `'`

```
document.getElementById(prdlnk').style.visibility = "visible";
```

Should be

```
document.getElementById('prdlnk')...
```

Also, why are you mixing quotes and double quotes? Pick a style and stick with it.

Comment: yeah, I caught it a sec ago... thanks. (missed it on the copy/paste)

Comment: So, does that mean it fixed the problem? Or is it something else?

Comment: Sorry, but correcting punctuation doesn't fix the problem.  Place of failure occurs when the current time exceeds the expired time.  Is there a way to check the visibility status of a link?  If so, restoration of the link would only happen when needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
var disable = (day === 0 && (MigTime >= nStart && MigTime < nExpired));
```

In this line of code, what is the intent behind day === 0?  === is a test for object type and value, it's not an assignment operator.  try day = 0